# run cronjob 1 hour after the last run finished

Tags: python, django, cron

I have a django cron and run it with linux crontab every hour. But I want to change the crontab to run the django cron 1 hour after the last execute finished. How can I do that?

It is the crontab:

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/python3.8 /django/vira/manage.py runcrons
```

And this is django-cron:

```
from django_cron import CronJobBase, Schedule
from . import runner


# create a class extending CronJobBase
class PushCronJob(CronJobBase):
    RUN_EVERY_MINS = 10
    schedule = Schedule(run_every_mins=RUN_EVERY_MINS)
    code = "vira_app.runner"

    def do(self):
        runner.run_spider()
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can run a cron job every minute and check if it has been an hour since it ran.

Comment: How? ... for example, cronjob start at 11:30 and end in 11:50 ... I want to start next cronjob at 12:50, not at 12:30

Comment: For this you will need some kind of memory where you can store last time the cron was executed. You might have to update it every time at the end of the execution

Comment: Then calculate if its been an hour then run the task again.